# varbinary to varchar or nvarchar

Tags: sql-server

When retrieving a text value, which has been stored in a `varbinary` field, and converting back to text, is there a way to determine whether it was stored as a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` string?  If it is unknown, telling the `CONVERT` function it is a `NVARCHAR` string, when it is in fact `VARCHAR` will return gibberish.  Run the below for an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.Temp;

CREATE TABLE Temp(
   ID INT IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL
  ,Test VARBINARY(50) NULL 
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Temp (Test) VALUES( CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), 'varchar test string'));
INSERT INTO dbo.Temp (Test) VALUES( CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), N'nvarchar test string'));

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Test) AS [VARCHAR], CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Test) AS [NVARCHAR]
FROM dbo.Temp;
```

Comment: What is the reason for the requirement? Why wouldn't they just be stored as strings? For `varchar` converting from `binary` can return different results under different collations too.

Comment: As an aside, [please stop declaring `varchar`/`nvarchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @Martin, The background for the question is related to encryption.  There is a scenario where I think different value types may have been inserted using EncryptByKey and when I DecryptByKey is doesn't always return correctly depending on which type is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really possible in general.

The full range from `0x00` to `0xFF` is valid for `varchar` and from `0x0000` to `0xFFFF` for `nvarchar` so it is impossible to distinguish between two bytes that represent 2 varchar characters or a single `nvarchar` character.

`0x4141` could be `'AA'` or `N'䅁'`

If `DATALENGTH` is odd then you know it is `varchar` though.

Also if the text is primarily standard ASCII as in your example then it will contain a lot of `0x00` when stored as binary if `nvarchar`.

This is probably not a character you expect to reasonably find at all in `varchar` strings so the presence of that could be taken as evidence that the string is `nvarchar`.

Comment: It was also just recommended to me that if different types are going to be encrypted to the binary field, that I should have an additional column to indicate what type was encrypted.

Comment: Didn't I also read that Microsoft doesn't guarantee that conversions from any other datatype to binary and back will be consistent between SQL versions?

Comment: @KennethFisher - Yes. This is stated in [binary and varbinary](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx). The section on [`DECRYPTBYKEY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx) does give an example with `nvarchar` though...